# Cython C++ static methods in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, cython

## Problem

I have a template class in C++ that has a static method. It looks more or less like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    static std::shared_ptr<Foo<T>> doSth();
}
```

so in C++ you would call it like: `Foo<Int>::doSth();`. In Cython however, the way to call static methods is by using the classname as a namespace:

```
cdef extern from "Bar.h" namespace "Bar":
    shared_ptr[Bar] doSth()  # assuming shared_ptr is already declared
```

but this has no notion of templates. Obviously, simply passing `Foo<T>` as a namespace doesn't work, because it translates to `Foo<T>::doStr()` in C++, no concrete type is substituted for T.

## Question

How would you do that in Cython? Is there a way, or a workaround?

Comment: Shouldn't this work like explained for non-static methods in the documentation? http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#templates

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Writing `cdef extern from "Foo.h" namespace "Foo": shared_ptr[Foo[T]] doSth[T]()` doesn't work either. That's because cython generates C++ code like: `Foo::doSth<int>();` -- the template parameter after Foo is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: This answer was right at the time it was written (and does still work) but you should now use [@Robertwb's answer to this question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39117335/4657412) to do this properly.

---

I don't think you can do it directly in Cython. You could create very thin wrapper of a normal (non-static-method) c++ template function

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Foo<T>> Foo_T_doSth<T>() {
   return Foo<T>::doSth();
}
```

and then wrap this method in Cython

```
cdef extern from "..."
    shared_ptr[T] Foo_T_doSth[T]()
```

---

As an aside, the recommended way of wrapping static methods in Cython looks to be (from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/xaErUq2yY0s)

```
cdef extern from "...":
   cdef Foo_doSth "Foo::doSth"()  # not declared as a memeber
```

(by specifying the actual function to use as a string). This doesn't help you here because it doesn't cope with templates. It may have been me who mis-advised you on the way you were trying...

Comment: Wrapping it works fine for me, thank you once again. I was just hoping I can avoid tinkering around my C++ code, but it's still super cool. I'll switch to the recommended way :)

Answer (score 10):

Static methods are now directly supported by Cython; the namespace hack is no longer necessary or recommended.

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Foo[T]:
        @staticmethod
        shared_ptr[Foo[T]] doSth()  # assuming shared_ptr is already declared

cdef shared_ptr[Foo[int]] shared_ptr_value = Foo[int].doSth()
```

http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#static-member-method

Comment: Where the syntax "cdef ... = function" is described? I couldn't find it in Cython documentation. How can it be used if doSth has an argument?